# Setting a cookie is not saving

Tags: php, cookies

I have setup POSTMAN to test an external API and it's setting a cooke as follows:

```
visa=319134-355996-1-1549389451--eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjlDRkRFRDg0NDhEMzcwM0NCNTQ5QjhCRTU2N0JCMDkyNTMxOEZDMUQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJuUDN0aEVqVGNEeTFTYmktVm51d2tsTVlfQjAifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NDkzODk0NTEsImV4cCI6MTU0OTM5MzA1MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zc28ubmF2aWdhdG9ybG9naW4uY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zc28ubmF2aWdhdG9ybG9naW4uY29tL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjM5ZDljOWU5LTRjOWYtNGY0Mi05ZGNkLTYxZmE3YmM4NTNmNyIsInN1YiI6Ijk4MzdiZjg0LTU3MzEtNGY0Yi04ZjQzLWE3MzE5MDkwYmFhNiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU0OTM4OTQ1MSwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJlbWFpbCIsIm9wZW5pZCIsInByb2ZpbGUiLCJvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.cBW6nbXvMZCwg!hiuPlks2bXhu!RQxwpzDBvl!!1QhmYxyeDoBGidDSXu89YxsxVlpkvAYbq6mgEaOlZFwuieOM_Z7KZqOJXHrtP460xc21eyau1DSyJalW9nkEO6DjxemRO2o3P4q10iIpupbmsd39TkcaBGhe9mHnqSqH8fveaTExGDimnBchqfswPYX2yUZSN1HbzadiPpKL5LAU9t!kQuLmV_LvuNr2QoqmZW!03RYpv648GGvAueLkr2VGVRkkJT!upfIWJ6cJbeLrdfY315xp88ZTkC9p5uNl6GnJwQEBGSSbtpjIEd6Pc339zHGpMyz4cVc2vNJfEpT1R1g-654b43210dcc68d962ecdcea1e06e767f742a360765a915b78670ca64eb91713-4AAB7A1E3261EB00CF799B573E23A5949C8BA4C42BCCA72D698DBAD1D5C6D8EC-307C7C7C7C317C556E646566696E6564; path=/; domain=.backup.management; Secure; HttpOnly; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```

I'm trying to implement this in PHP, so I tried setting the cookie like this:

```
setcookie ( 'visa', $login["visa"], time()+3600, '/', 'backup.management', 1, 1);
```

(where `$login["visa"]` is the long string)

However when I try to echo the cookie using `echo $_COOKIE["visa"];` it tells me its not valid.

Have I missed something when setting the cookie in my PHP?

Comment: What is the error log saying?

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is a super global containing _request_ variables - meaning cookies that were present in the HTTP request that started the current thread. As such, setting a cookie via `setcookie` does not modify the `$_COOKIE` super global in the same thread. See _Common Pitfalls_ under the [Notes](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-notes) section of the function documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try in simple way for `SET`

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

and for `GET`

```
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

Comment: I just tried this, but its telling me `Notice: Undefined index: TestCookie in /home/i/t/itl/public_html/admin/system/pages/dev-test/charlie.php on line 22`

Comment: Any thoughts itch this?

Comment: first we have to do execute this in code : setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600); 
into charlie.php then refresh/reload

, reload is compulsory because cookie stored in browser after reload.  

now you can execute this code : 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie'])) {

  echo  $_COOKIE['lg'];
}